# calling MySql databse/tables in powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have written a script to connect to my MySql server and have a list of all the databses on this server and all the tables in each database and it works fine, it lists the databases then it lists all the tables together in one column, i have tried making it look more neat but unfortunately without success, i would like it to list the tables as such:

```
FirstDatabase:
FirstTable
SecondTable
ThirdTable....
SecondDatabase:
FirstTable
SecondTable
ThirdTable...
```

instead of that it combines all the tables together. Here is my code:

```
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data") 

$myconnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$myconnection.ConnectionString = “server=MySqlServer;user id=$usr;password=$pwd;database=dbm;pooling=false”
$myconnection.Open()

$Query = "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql','sys','information_schema','performance_schema') GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA;"
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($Query, $myconnection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$null = $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$results = $DataSet.Tables[0] 
$results

foreach ($result in $results) {

    $TableQuery = "USE " + $result.TABLE_SCHEMA + ";  SHOW TABLES;"
    $TableCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($TableQuery, $myconnection)
    $TableDataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($TableCommand)
    $TableDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $null = $TableDataAdapter.fill($TableDataSet)
    $TableResults = $TableDataSet.Tables[0]
}

$myconnection.Close()
```

running `$results` gives the databases on the server.
running `$TableResults` gives the tables in all the databases together

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing the individual results to the screen as strings, you'll want to create an object per table, with both the table and database names as properties:

```
# ...
$null = $DataAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$results = $DataSet.Tables[0] 

# don't output anything yet!

$tables = foreach ($result in $results) {
    $TableQuery = "USE " + $result.TABLE_SCHEMA + ";  SHOW TABLES;"
    $TableCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($TableQuery, $myconnection)
    $TableDataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($TableCommand)
    $TableDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $null = $TableDataAdapter.fill($TableDataSet)
    $TableResults = $TableDataSet.Tables[0]
    foreach($tableRow in $TableResults){
        # Create a new object with both the database and table name
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Database  = $result.TABLE_SCHEMA
            TableName = $tableRow.Item(0)
        }
    }
}

$myconnection.Close()
```

Now that `$tables` contains objects with both properties, you can use either one of them to modify how PowerShell formats them in the output:

```bsh
PC C:\> $tables |Format-Table TableName -GroupBy Database

   Database: db1

TableName
-----
Table1
Table2
Table3

   Database: db2

TableName
-----
Table1
Table2
Table3

   Database: db3

TableName
-----
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

Comment: thank you for clearing that up, it worked perfectly.